# simple accumulation but keyerror : 0

Tags: python, dataframe

i have data set. i want to save my data in df2.

| RegionNo | Internet |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |

expected :

| RegionNo | Internet |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 |
| 2 | 6 |

```
def accu():
    k = 0
    for i in range(len(df) - 1):
        if df.loc[i, "RegionNo"] == df.loc[i + 1, "RegionNo"]:
            df2.loc[k, "Internet"] = df2.loc[k, "Internet"] + df.loc[i, "Internet"]
            df2.loc[k, "RegionNo"] = df.loc[i, "RegionNo"]

        else:
            k = k + 1
            df2.loc[k, "RegionNo"] = df.loc[i + 1, "RegionNo"]
            df2.loc[k, "Internet"] = df2.loc[k, "Internet"] + df.loc[i, "Internet"]
```

but every time i try my code, keyError occured:
keyerror : 0

```
File "C:/Users/Monet/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/new_main.py", line 9, in accu
    df2.loc[k, "Internet"] = df2.loc[k, "Internet"] + df.loc[i, "Internet"]
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 925, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_tuple(key)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1100, in _getitem_tuple
    return self._getitem_lowerdim(tup)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 838, in _getitem_lowerdim
    section = self._getitem_axis(key, axis=i)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1164, in _getitem_axis
    return self._get_label(key, axis=axis)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1113, in _get_label
    return self.obj.xs(label, axis=axis)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 3776, in xs
    loc = index.get_loc(key)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3363, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 0
```

Comment: What is `i` in the first iteration of `for i in range(len(df) - 1)`?

Comment: for reading line by line of df.

Comment: Please include the full traceback error.

Comment: Okay, but what is your *question* about this?

Comment: it occurs key error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wanted:

```
print(df.groupby('RegionNo').sum())
```

For example:

```
from pandas import DataFrame

data = [
    {'RegionNo': 1, 'Internet': 1},
    {'RegionNo': 1, 'Internet': 2},
    {'RegionNo': 1, 'Internet': 3},
    {'RegionNo': 1, 'Internet': 4},
    {'RegionNo': 2, 'Internet': 1},
    {'RegionNo': 2, 'Internet': 2},
    {'RegionNo': 2, 'Internet': 3}
]

df = DataFrame(data)
df2 = df.groupby('RegionNo').sum()
print(df2)
```

Result:

```
        Internet
RegionNo
1             10
2              6
```

You haven't shared how you created `df2`, but it likely doesn't have the position you're trying to access, which causes the error you're asking about. (by the way, it helps if you actually ask a clear question at the end of the explanation in the question text, so people don't have to drag it out). And as the code above shows, you don't need to access `df2` that way either.

Comment: Can you fix my code?

Comment: No, because A.) there is no reason to, your code tries to do something that `pandas` already does for you, B.) I already explained what the problem was, so it shouldn't be too hard for you to fix it yourself and C.) StackOverflow isn't here to do your work for you, but to provide answers to technical questions. "Can you fix my code?" is not such a question.